# Should properties of class in Kotlin be private and how to access them?

Tags: kotlin

Aloha! While reading Kotling Language Reference I noticed that the keyword "private" for properties of a class is never used (always default which is public). It also said that getters and setters are generated automatically.
So I created class and made its fields private. However, when I create object of the class, I cannot see the fields and no setters and getters are available, unless I write them myself.
So what's the rule here? Leave visibility modifier default (public) or make them private and provide mutator methods?
Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The whole idea of a property is that it encapsulates a field and its accessors in a single entity. If you need to be able to access and modify a property of a class from the outside, you should keep the property public. If you need to be able to read from the outside but not update it, you can define a public property with a private accessor.

Changing a default accessor to a custom one will not affect the clients of your class, because under the hood the compiler will always generate accessor methods, and the clients of the class will use those methods and will not access the underlying field directly.

You should never write explicit getter or mutator methods which are separate from the property accessors.

Comment: So it is practically impossible to directly get to the property right? And I am safe to always keep them public? (I came from java where everything should be private) How about internal?

Comment: What do you mean by "directly get to the property"? A backing field of a property can only be accessed through reflection. `internal` visibility should be used if the property is only accessed from the same module.

Comment: I meant as in Java, if you make field public, you can access it without getter and setter, which is not good. But I got it now, thank you.

Comment: You should understand the difference between a field and a property. Basicly: Property = field + getter (+ setter, if mutable).

Comment: @yole this definition and explanation should be made available in the kotlin docs, as it's vital. The docs don't explain the idea behind this, which leaves you confused as to how things work and why. Please improve the docs

Comment: The problem is that _everything_ in Kotlin is a property; `var` and `val` are always properties. I agree that most getter/setter methods are public in most Java codebases, however in my experience most fields in a well designed architecture DO NOT correspond with properties and they are declared `private`. If `var` and `val` were exclusively a property construct separate from a field construct, I would agree with the public default decision, but this is not the case.